# GetOpenFileName - has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to write simple OpenFile dialog via WinAPI in C++. The problem appears when I want call GetOpenFileName, I get error 'test.exe has triggered a breakpoint', even I use example from MSDN.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char szFile[260];  

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using VisualStudio 2015 Community and Windows 10.

callstack:

> ```
> > KernelBase.dll!762882b2()   Unknown
>   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]    
>   GROOVEEX.DLL!5891738e() Unknown
>   GROOVEEX.DLL!588efb8d() Unknown
>   GROOVEEX.DLL!587c548c() Unknown
>   GROOVEEX.DLL!5879b0c5() Unknown
>   GROOVEEX.DLL!5879b030() Unknown
>   [External Code]
> ```

Comment: Try calling `CoInitialize()` at the start and `CoUninitialize()` at the end.

Comment: I pasted the above code into a new project, built it Release x86, ran the program, picked a file. The program exited with no breakpoint. Share a stack trace of your breakpoint.

Comment: this usually be due to corruption of the heap when run under debugger and "the output window may have more diagnostic information". and problem not related to this code, but to another code from your app, which you not paste here

Comment: I even wrote new application with new project in VisualStudio and code you can see above, and still, it doesn't work. CoInitialize didn't help.
My callstack: http://pastebin.com/w78RXApz

Comment: When you use GetOpenFileName() then you get to debug not just your code but also all of the shell extensions that are installed on your machine and get injected into your process.  Like Office Groove, shovelware that got added to about every Windows machine after Microsoft hired Ray Ozzie and bought out his company.  Whose claim to fame is Lotus Notes, must be about the most despised software ever written :)  Ozzie is long gone but the shovelware is not.  Press F5 to keep going but do keep in mind that you just saw the canary in the coal mine keel over and die.

Comment: A call stack can be made human-readable by using [Microsoft's symbol server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588.aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server). That'll at least give you the top of the call stack. But Hans Passant is probably right: You've got 'helpful' shell extensions installed, that weren't prepared for ... anything, probably.

Comment: @RbMm that program is entirely self-contained and still exhibits the behavior; where else could the problem be? Whatever the case, Hans Passant probably identified the faulty module from the stack trace that was posted; I do wonder why it's failing in this scenario but not in others...

Comment: @andlabs - i make self comment before OP add stack trace. from it visible that problem faster of all in GROOVEEX.DLL . however need look under debugger. and GetOpenFileName ver common function. if call it from notepad (simply open file dialog exec) - also break point will be ? here also GROOVEEX.DLL i think. and breakpoint is under debugger or when program run separate without debugger ?

Comment: @RbMm I wouldn't be surprised if GROOVEEX.DLL or something that uses it is relying on some precondition most Windows programs have met (for instance, that there is a window, or that there is an active message pump) but that this one does not. Now I wonder if there's a way to enumerate shell extensions...

Comment: @andlabs - "uses it is relying on some precondition most Windows programs have met" - i not think so. but without debugging on target system very hard say exactly

Comment: If nobody has been able to reproduce this (I admit I haven't tried) it is also possible that the Office Groove installation is corrupted on the OPs machine.  Or that it is interacting badly with his anti-virus software, or any of at least a dozen other possible explanations along those lines.